# WebGazer.js unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, eye-tracking

So I'm trying to play around with [WebGazer](https://webgazer.cs.brown.edu/) but I'm already stuck at loading the js file. The webgazer.js file consists of 140k line of codes, but when I load my page the js file only loads until line 94k.

[image]

I don't want to use NPM cause it's causing me a lot of hassle to install & run the NPM. How do I fix this problem? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like when I save the webgazer.js in my project it is not uploaded fully to the server. I had to upload multiple times (3x) in order to fully upload the webgazer.js

I was using PhpStorm and ec2 instance (AWS) for my development server